# I cannot start filebeat with configuration file to read from file and write into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

trying to start file beat with configuration file filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: filestream
    id: input1-id
    paths:
      - /home/yasser/data/sample1.log
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]
  index: ["test-index"]
```

getting error:
Exiting: can not convert 'object' into 'string' accessing 'output.elasticsearch.index' (source:'/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml')
...fail!

I tried to start file beat to read from one log file and write into elasticsearch. it seems an error with index. it is not starting

Answer (score 0):

The `index` field is a string, not an array, as described in the [filebeat documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/8.7/elasticsearch-output.html#index-option-es) .

Try to replace the `index: ["test-index"]` with `index: "test-index"`.